# IP Addresses, Ranges or Blocks?

Tags: ip, subnet

So there are A,B,C,D,E ranges like 1-126, etc... but in an IP address, what means 192 out of 192.168.12.4? Is it a class A block or what? I have trouble understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Classful routing hasn't been done since 1993 - so this class A, B, C junk doesn't mean much anymore.  Nowadays, there is [Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).  Regardless, an IPv4 address is just a 32-bit number.  It's broken down into 8-bit chunks and printed in decimal in the dot notation for your human brain's convenience, but it doesn't mean anything in reality.  All that 192 means is that the first 8 bits of your IP address are `11000000`.

Your IP address *is* a bit of a special case, in that it's part of the 16-bit [private network range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_private_addresses) for IPv4 (192.168.0.0  to 192.168.255.255).

Comment: Also, look at http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Comment: The third response on the above question covers classes.  192.0.0.0/8 would be a class A size block, but 192 is in the old class C range.

Comment: A couple of ranges are reserved for private use, as described in http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html and are not routed on the internet. 192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x (actually 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x) and 10.x.x.x are private ranges. 192.x.x.x by itself isn't.